# What is the shortcut key for object opacity in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, shortcuts

I am changing object opacity in Illustrator manually. Is there a keyboard shortcut to make an object's opacity 90%?

Comment: Have you checked the list of shortcuts in Illustrator?  https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Edit>>Keyboard shortcuts and assign your own shortcuts.

Now you can just type the number to the corresponding opacity as we do in Photoshop.

Here's my example in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are no default shortcuts, but you can set your own in Keyboard Shortcuts:

[image]